# Weird issue, some times it drops tooltip style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Weird issue, some times it drops tooltip style

using vb asp.net, bootstrap and javascript

Below I hava a simple bootstrap & asp tool tip. Tooltip has white background, text is inc, some padding and tooltip does not disappear unless your mouse is out of fouse.
This is perfect and exactly what I want. so what is the issue?

Issue: On some computer it display the style tooltip, which is good but on some computers it is displaying the default tooltip.
Default tooltip: grey background, lil to no padding, small text, and tooltip disappear after 5 secs. I do not want this tooltip.

note* inside asp:Label there is no 'Title' so I end up using 'ToolTip'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='my text random' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" ToolTip='my tooltip' runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am guessing it is not running bootstrap tooltip style on some computers. any idea why that could be?

Comment: You need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, css, JavaScript) that allows replicating your issue exactly. That's the only way you can hope for sensible answers.

Comment: ok does this helps?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Edit your question and post your **COMPLETE** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon. In other words, post the **output HTML** and everything that's required for me to be able to replicate the issue. The result of your snippet now is a completely blank, empty page.

Comment: is this good now?

Comment: You still haven't included any links to Bootstrap css and JavaScript and so, it's impossible to know which version of Bootstrap you are actually using...